# Mongodb : upsert and positional operator when query is false

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have a database like this :

```
Db.collection.object
{
    "item1": [{
        "quantity":"",
        "price":""
    }],

    "item2": [{
        "quantity":"",
        "price":""
    }],
}
```

I want to update "item2.quantity" so I'm using this (it's working):

```
 db.object.updateOne({"item2":{$exists:true}},{$set:{"item2.$.quantity":"55"}})
```

But sometimes, I need to create "item2" so I want to do "upsert:true" so my "update function" will create the document.

```
 db.object.updateOne({"item2":{$exists:true}},{$set:{"item2.$.quantity":"55"}}, {upsert:true})
```

But it does nothing because the query function is false ?

**[thread1] WriteError: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query.**

Comment: Is the collection right? Because I've notices you have {{"item1" [...],...}} insteado of {{"item1" :[...],...}}. It seems that the tow dots are missing.

Comment: Yes it's just a typo, the first command is working but no the second one.

Answer (score 0):

To use the $, You must include the array field as part of the query document.

If the query matches the array using a negation operator, such as $ne, $not, or $nin, then you cannot use the positional operator to update values from this array.

Your $exists:true probably falls under negation

[Official Document Here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)